# Save() not passing anything in my id field

Tags: php, cakephp

My debug value is set to `2` and I think because there's no data being passed here I'm getting a validation error, which is why this was first appearing to be a phantom error. I'm not sure though as I'm still new to Cakephp.

I have an `Addresses` controller that is passing data to my model that looks like so:

```
public function add() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Address->create();
        if ($this->Address->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The address has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The address could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }   
    $users = $this->Address->User->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users'));
}
```

However when I debug using `die(debug($this->request->data))))` I get the following result, revealing that there is nothing being passed in my `id` field:

```
/app/Controller/AddressesController.php (line 61)
array(
    'Address' => array(
        'id' => '',
        'building_number' => '1',
        'street_name' => 'Test Street',
        'city' => 'Cityville',
        'post_code' => 'N113AQ',
        'user_id' => '1'
    )
)
```

Any ideas as to why nothing is being passed into the `id` field? I have controllers working in **exactly** the same way for different tables that go off perfectly fine.

My `Address.id` field in my database is set to auto increment and is named correctly, `$this->Address->save()` returns false too.

Comment: A nothing in id is good actually as id is automatically created at the time . For primary issue of not saving data , you need to check it must be some validation issue. CakePhp by default validates the data before saving.

Comment: Is your database properly configured with id as an auto-incrementing number as the primary key? CakePHP uses a lot of automagic so you must also make sure your variables are named appropriately.

Comment: is the id an auto-incremented ??

Comment: Do you have a user in the database with an id of 1?

Comment: Try making the error reporting as sensitive as possible and see if you get something. Make sure you're using the default config for error handling: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html

Comment: @Abhishek you were absolutely right, it was a validation error! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If $this->request->data contains an array element named after the form’s model, and that array contains a empty value of the model’s primary key(here the id), then the FormHelper will create an add form for that record. For add method HTTP POST verb is ok. POST is for create and PUT is for edit in CakePHP. You can check validations and change the request type to non-GET. It may work.

```
if (!$this->request->is('get')){
  //Save logic here
}
```

Comment: This isn't related to the question, the data is POSTed and makes it to the `save()` call.